# Blank document and unhandled promise rejection when making an add subdocument request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on my first request that would add a subdocument to a document in MongoDB and I'm struggling with it. My database is a collection of users, and each user has an array of words they working on learning to translate in the application I am building. I am currently having two issues

1. when I make a request in postman to add a new word to my user's array of words, I add a new object that has ID, but none of the other property value pairs that I have in the word sub-model, and in the request(greek, english, success,  timestamp).
2. my command prompt gives me the following errors

> (node:8320) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3) (node:8320)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: user validation
> failed: words.0.greek: Path `greek` is required., words.0.english:
> Path `english` is required., words.0.success: Path `success` is
> required., words.0.timeStamp: Path `timeStamp` is required.

The second error is confusing because in my mind it should be word.greek and words.english to get the value from the each word object. However, it adds a 0 between the object and its property/value pair.

My mongoose model for the subdocument is as follows

```
const wordSchema = new Schema({
  greek: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 1,
    index: { unique: true, sparse: true },
  },
  english: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1
  },
  success: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  timeStamp: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
});
```

This is my request to add the word to the User's array of words.

```
router.post("/update/:id",(req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body.greek)
    var greek = req.body.greek;
    var english = req.body.english;
    var success = req.body.success;
    var timeStamp = req.body.timeStamp
    var newWord = {
        greek: greek,
        english: english,
        success: success,
        timeStamp: timeStamp
    }
    User.findById(req.params.id)
    .then((user) => {
      user.words.push(newWord);
      user.save()
      res.status(200).json(user)
      .catch((err) => {res.status(400).json(err)})
    })
    .catch((err) => {res.status(400).json("Error: "+err)})
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've done some googling on adding subdocuments to a document, but I still haven't found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of fetching and then updating the document you can directly update the document in one DB call.

```
router.post("/update/:id",(req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body.greek)
    var greek = req.body.greek;
    var english = req.body.english;
    var success = req.body.success;
    var timeStamp = req.body.timeStamp
    var newWord = {
        greek: greek,
        english: english,
        success: success,
        timeStamp: timeStamp
    }
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, {
            $push: {
                words: newWord
            }
        })
    .then((user) => {
      if(!user){
                return res.status(404).json({ 
                    message: 'Not User matches given ID'
                });
            }

            res.status(200).json(user);
    })
    .catch((err) => {res.status(400).json("Error: "+err)})
});
```

Comment: I implemented that fix, but unfortunately I am still getting the object with only an id for my new word.

Comment: you mean only objectId is present in the newly created subdoc ?

Comment: Yes, but I think I'm getting closer to the culprit. I added a console.log(newWord) before my findOneAndUpdate method, and it says that greek, english, success, and timeStamp are undefined.

Comment: It looks like req.body is blank. Time for some more googling!

Comment: You know what, somewhere along the line I accidentally switched my postman request from JSON to text and it was breaking everything. Now your solution works perfectly (but I've discored a new error #codingLife) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

one thing I see is `user.save()` will return a promise, which you do not handle, hence the document will not be save. maybe consider:

```
User.findById(req.params.id)
.then(async (user) => {
    user.words.push(newWord);
    await user.save()
    res.status(200).json(user)
    .catch((err) => {res.status(400).json(err)})
})
.catch((err) => {res.status(400).json("Error: "+err)})
```